# Всё перепробовал, но при обновлении страницы заново подает отправку формы

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin, mysqli

Имею отправку данных с формы, всё хорошо, в базу добавляется, также делаю вывод данных с БД на страницу, но при обновлении страницы просит подтвердить повторную отправку данных, и добавляет повторно последний запрос. Вот собственно код (html и php в одном файле php)

```html
<!DOCtype html>
<html>
<head>

 <title>Запись в БД через форму на php</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form method="POST" action="" >
   <label>От кого: </label><br>
  <input name="name" type="text" value="" placeholder="Имя"/><br>
   <label>Сообщение: </label><br>
  <textarea name="text" type="text" cols="30" rows="20" placeholder="Текст"/></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить"/>

 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Также php

```html
<?php

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['text'])){
    // Переменные с формы
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $text = $_POST['text'];

    $_SESSION["name"]= $name;
    $_SESSION["text"]= $text;
    // Параметры для подключения
    $db_host = "localhost";
    $db_user = "root"; // Логин БД
    $db_password = ""; // Пароль БД
    $db_base = "sega"; // Имя БД
    $db_table = "mytable"; // Имя Таблицы БД

    // Подключение к базе данных
    $mysqli = new mysqli($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_base);
    $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

  $mysqli->query (
  "CREATE TABLE `sega`.`mytable`(
      `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      `name` VARCHAR(20),
      `text` VARCHAR(255),
   `regdate` DATE
  )
  ");

  $errors = array();

  if( $_POST['name'] == '' ) {
      $errors[] = 'Введите Ваше имя!';
  }

  if( $_POST['text'] == '' ) {
      $errors[] = 'Введите Ваш текст!';
  }
  if ( empty($errors) ) {
    $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ".$db_table." (name,text) VALUES ('$name', '$text')");

  }else {
     //Errors are present
     echo $errors['0'] . '<hr><br>';
     }



    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM `mytable`");
    while($r1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {

    echo 'Имя: '.$r1['name'].'<br>'.'Сообщение: '.$r1['text'];
    echo '<hr>';
    }

}

?>
```

Пробовал различные Header но не помогало, в случае с header выдаёт ошибку (Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by)
Перечитал множество вариантов в интернете, ничего не помогло, думаю в моём коде какая то ошибка. Прошу помощи

Comment: `header('Location: ....` до вызова header никакого текста не должно быть отправлено на вывод

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой и правильный, на мой взгляд, вариант, это разнести по разным файлам, отделить html от php кода.
Например:
index.php будет содержать:

```
<!DOCtype html>
<html>
    <head>

     <title>Запись в БД через форму на php</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <?php
        require_once 'form.php';
        require_once 'list.php';
    ?>

    </body>
```

form.php :

```
 <form method="POST" action="send.php" >
   <label>От кого: </label><br>
  <input name="name" type="text" value="" placeholder="Имя"/><br>
   <label>Сообщение: </label><br>
  <textarea name="text" type="text" cols="30" rows="20" placeholder="Текст"/></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить"/>
```

list.php :

```
<?php

//Тут необходимо прописать параметры подключения к БД
//А лучше их вынести в отдельное место, например создать config.php


$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM `mytable`");
    while($r1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {

    echo 'Имя: '.$r1['name'].'<br>'.'Сообщение: '.$r1['text'];
    echo '<hr>';
    }
```

send.php :

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['text'])){
// Переменные с формы
$name = $_POST['name'];
$text = $_POST['text'];

$_SESSION["name"]= $name;
$_SESSION["text"]= $text;
// Параметры для подключения
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root"; // Логин БД
$db_password = ""; // Пароль БД
$db_base = "sega"; // Имя БД
$db_table = "mytable"; // Имя Таблицы БД

// Подключение к базе данных
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_base);
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

  $mysqli->query (
  "CREATE TABLE `sega`.`mytable`(
      `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      `name` VARCHAR(20),
      `text` VARCHAR(255),
    `regdate` DATE
  )
  ");
  $errors = array();

  if( $_POST['name'] == '' ) {
      $errors[] = 'Введите Ваше имя!';
  }

  if( $_POST['text'] == '' ) {
      $errors[] = 'Введите Ваш текст!';
  }
  if ( empty($errors) ) {
    $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ".$db_table." (name,text) VALUES ('$name', '$text')");

  }else {
     //Errors are present
     echo $errors['0'] . '<hr><br>';
     }
```

}

в файле send.php, после успешной записи в базу, добавьте редирект на index.php. P.S. Код, который я привел, не проверял на наличие логических и синтаксических ошибок, писал на скорую руку, только для того, чтоб чуть моей мысли была более понятной:)

Comment: Спасибо огромное, всё получилось, а то голову ломал долгое время!!!
Только ещё один вопрос, если у меня срабатывает ошибка, например вводимые поля пустые, то он меня отправляет на страницу файла send.php и там уже выводит ошибку с названием ошибки и ошибки перенаправления

Comment: По хорошему нужно использовать сессии, писать в сессию ошибку и перенаправлять на страницу ввода данных.

Comment: @titan-ser Если нужно просто и срочно, то как временное решение можно использовать конструкцию такого вида: if( $_POST['text'] == '' ) 
     {
    print "<script language='Javascript' type='text/javascript'>
                    <!--
                    alert ('Слишком короткое сообщение :)');
                    window.location.href = \"https://ваш_сайт.ru/index.php\" 
                    -->
                    </script>";   
                exit();
    }